# put html menu on jsfiddle. unclosed regular expression

Tags: html, jsfiddle

I can not run this code. I have unclosed regular expression from what I see all tags are closed correctly. Maybe at the end of the confusion but the system shows an error even at the beginning of the code.

[jsfiddle.net/n5u2wwjg/176703/](http://Fiddle)

on codepen its works [codepen.io/romanown/pen/PdERze](http://Codepen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some closing tags missing - Correct your `render()`

```
<div>
    <ul class="top-menu">
        <li>
            <a href="">Главная home page</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Портфолио</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div>
                <a href="" class="dropdown">Shops</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li> Column 1
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="">Element of list</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="">Element of list</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="">Элемент списка</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="">Элемент списка</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="">Элемент списка</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="">Элемент списка</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="">Элемент списка</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="">Элемент списка</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <ul>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="" class="link-image">
                                    <img src="https://html5book.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/white-lady.jpg" />
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <h3 class="image-header">Header of picture</h3>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="">Блог</a>
                    </li>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. You have a little not so it turned out as it should but I found the problem in your code. Your help has been helpful. everything works fine but the message about the unclosed expression remains.

Comment: I don't understand why I got the cons. this error message was not because of my code. now everything works but the error message remains. if the system is designed to receive help, you cannot be punished for asking for help. here  jsfiddle.net even the newly created React after the start of editing shows an error not closed expression even after I returned the code to its original state. I'm not making my mistake. http://jsfiddle.net/n5u2wwjg/176762/

Comment: Hi @romanown  http://jsfiddle.net/n5u2wwjg/176762/ there is no any error as such. It looks fine. What is error you are talking about?

Comment: red dot. red dot. when I add text then delete it still appears a red dot indicating that the expression is not closed.

Comment: Where are you adding text? However, please insert your code in here and click Beautify, you will know where you are missing closing tag - https://codebeautify.org/htmlviewer/